# In min(new_value, na.rm = T): no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

Tags: r

I estimated a model with four independent categorical variables.

```
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)
data(efc)
efc <- to_factor(efc, c161sex, e42dep, c172code)
mod <- lm(neg_c_7 ~ pos_v_4 + c12hour + e42dep + c172code,
          data = efc)
```

I would like to plot the model (its estimates and confidence intervals) showing only *two* from the four independent variables.

I had no issue when I ploted the complete model using the following command:

```
plot_model(mod)
```

However, when I select only the variables I want by using the argument `terms`:

```
plot_model(mod, terms=c("e42dep", "c172code"))
```

The `plot_model` didn't run correctly and the following warning messages came out:

```
Warning messages:
1: In min(new_value, na.rm = T) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In min(dat$conf.low) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In min(dat$estimate) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(dat$conf.high) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
5: In max(dat$estimate) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
6: In .axisPars(usr, log = log, nintLog = nint) : NaNs produced
```

Does anyone have a clue of what could be happening?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** This is due to the way that terms need to be specified for categorical variables in estimate plots.

<strike>I'm not sure exactly what the problem is, but it seems like it's a bug in how the terms are being subset from the full model results.</strike> When creating the model terms the categorical variables have their levels appended to the term names (except for the reference level), and then that dataframe is subset to include only the names passed to the `terms` argument.

<strike>A workaround is</strike> Therefore the correct way to call them is explicitly as such:

```
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)
data(efc)

efc <- to_factor(efc, c161sex, e42dep, c172code)

mod <- lm(neg_c_7 ~ pos_v_4 + c12hour + e42dep + c172code, data = efc)
```

You can see the resulting names of the terms by pulling out the coefficient names from the model object

```
levels(efc$e42dep)
#[1] "1" "2" "3" "4"
levels(efc$c172code)
#[1] "1" "2" "3" 

names(mod$coefficients)
#[1] "(Intercept)" "pos_v_4"     "c12hour"     "e42dep2"     "e42dep3"    
#[6] "e42dep4"     "c172code2"   "c172code3"

#plot just the estimates of e42dep and c172code

plot_model(mod, type="est", terms=c("e42dep2",
                                    "e42dep3",
                                    "e42dep4",
                                    "c172code2",
                                    "c172code3"))
```

[image: sjPlot with categorical variables]

Note that some other types of plots support calling just the variable name or adding indexing, e.g.,

```
plot_model(mod, type="pred", terms=c("e42dep [2:4]", "c172code [2,3]"))
plot_model(mod, type="pred", terms=c("e42dep", "c172code"))
```

but this has not been implemented for estimate plots yet.

Comment: This is actually not the workaround, but the intendend way of how this should work, so you can show / remove even specific levels from categorical variables. Maybe this could be revised, in order to show some other default behaviour?

Comment: Ah, I see. I had assumed that the default behavior would be to plot all levels when just the variable name was supplied. Just for clarification, I also get the same error if I call the factors as such `plot_model(mod, type="est", terms=c("e42dep [2,3]", "c172code [2,3]"))` which looks like it should work based on the documentation? Also it does work when `type="pred"` but not when `type="est"` .

Comment: Yes, I first implemented specifying levels, i.e. `terms=c("e42dep [2,3]", "c172code [2,3]"))` for marginal effects plots. Maybe I can also use this for plotting estimates, but this is currently not implemented.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I was confused about the expected behavior based on the documentation for the other types of plots. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! In the current dev-version (https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot), I implemented the same notation for `type = "est"`. I have also made this more clear in the function docs.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I should specify the `terms` names and not its categories. However, when I specified the categories names it worked properly.

> plot_model(mod, type="est", terms=c("e42dep2",
>                                       "e42dep3",
>                                       "e42dep4",
>                                       "c172code2",
>                                       "c172code3"))